# Where is WASM stuck - how do I find that?

Tags: debugging, webassembly

I am building a compiler for WASM,
however now my (quite complex) test program is stuck when executing it in Google Chrome.

How can I find out, in which function it is stuck? Except printing all functions it calls ofc. Is there an elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [integrated debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/wasm-debugging-2019/) in Chrome, or Firefox. You can browse instructions, place break points, step in/out of function calls, view the call stack, the memory bytes, etc.

To be able to see the source code of your language you may use source maps, or better, the [DWARF](https://dwarfstd.org/) format, because the source maps are a temporal solution at this time.

There are compilers that emit source maps and/or DWARF format, but in your case you might have to develop that yourself.